# best practices for restful webservice

Tags: android, web-services, rest, ios5

Tried to search for this online and didn't get very far, so I'm asking here. What are some of the best practices people have come across for building a website with a restful service? Is it good to combine them both into one or keep them as two separate applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it depends on a lot of things what's the best to do, what I probably would do is, I'll have a set of "backend" functionality what are doing the "business" things, and the web app will call these functions "directly", and they will be exported as web service calls too. In Java there are lots of handy framework making this very easy - like Spring + Jackson - and I'm sure this is the case in other languages too.

Comment: I ended up creating two components as in my suggestion. In the long run, I feel it's easier to build out two apps than just one, since the use case of each app will be tailored towards one purpose. Anyway, I guess it really depends on what you are working on.